# Java change full name to initial. last name

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a database of player names that i need converted for me to be able to further work with them (for example: I need Antonio Brown converted to A. Brown). My problem is that there are also names that only consist of the first name (for example Antonio) Therefore i get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`, is there another way to get what i want and why does it even with the if condition stil split?

```
if(spalte[1].contains(" ")){
   String[] me = spalte[0].split(" ", 2);
   String na = me[0].substring(0);
    name = na + ". " + me[1];
} else {
    name = spalte[1];
}
```

Comment: You need to check the size of the `String[]` returned by `split` before referencing an element that might not be there. Prosaically, it translates into running your converting code only if the original name `String` contains a whitespace. I would also recommend reinforcing your code to handle multiple white spaces (e.g. `Antonio H. Brown`, untrimmed `String`s, etc.).

Comment: checking for `spalte[1]` containing a space character and _then_ splitting `spalte[0]` on space looks like a bug to me: if `spalte[1]` contains a space `spalte[0]` might still not contain one and thus `me[1]` could result in the exception you get. Do you mean to always use either `spalte[0]` or `spalte[1]`?

Comment: @Thomas totally missed it, that was the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I highly recommend you to keep your code formatted and variables named properly. It helps not only others to understand a snippet better but also makes debugging a bit easier.

While working with arrays and `String::split`, you have to be careful with indices because they might overflow easily.

Do you need to make the code handle multiple spaces: `Antonio Light Brown -> A. L. Brown`? The steps are simple and practically the same for any number of names:

- Split by a space delimiter
- Shorten the `n-1` first partitions
- Concatenate the String back

Here is the code:

```
String split[] = name.trim().split(" ");     // Trim the multiple spaces inside to avoid empty parts
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();      // StringBuilder builds the String

for (int i=0; i<split.length; i++) {                      // Iterate the parts
    if (i<split.length -1) {                              // If not the last part
        sb.append(split[i].charAt(0)).append(". ");       // Append the first letter and a dot
    } else sb.append(split[i]);                           // Or else keep the entire word
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());           // StringBuilder::toString returns a composed String
```

Hypothetically: How would you handle names such as `O'Neil` or `de Anthony`? You can include the conditional concatenation in the `for-loop`.